# What does "ASP.NET 4.5 Async Pipeline" mean?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, parallel-processing, async-await

Having look at [current compatibility list for Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Compatibility) (as for 3.2.3 version) it says:

> C# 5.0 - **[supported]** async support

but

> ASP.NET 4.5 Async Pipeline - **[not supported]** *Needs an parallel processing pipeline with async support, not done*.

What does **Async Popeline** here mean (as well as "**parallel processing pipeline**") and how is it related to C# 5.0 async support (i.e., rather, what's the difference)?

Thank you!

Comment: I imagine it's referring to the first few items [in this list](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/aspnet-and-visual-studio-2012/whats-new).

Comment: Aha. I would say that's quite an answer. However, what's about "parallel processing pipeline"? (I guess, that's not directly (or even completely not) related to ASP.NET).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they're referring to supporting async/await in ASP.NET (WebForms, MVC, etc.), specifically that supporting it will require an HTTP pipeline that fully supports asynchronous operations.